# Losing data when macOS reboot or restart using chrome.storage?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I'm working a chrome extension development. I stored some data on Chrome using chrome.storage. Sometimes, my mac uses too much memory and I will just force to close all the apps and restart macOS to free the memory. It took a long time for my mac to restart. So I press the power button to reboot my mac. Later I successfully login to my system. It turned out that my data store in chrome via chrome.storage is lost.

Do you know what happened? How do I avoid this kind of issue?

Comment: The OS may cache data before writing it to disk, so you should wait for a few seconds before cycling the power, however if the browser was terminated before it writes the data to disk then you can't do anything about it other than upgrading your computer.

Comment: Weird. I don't know how chrome write data to disk. I'm testing my chrome-extension for a couple of times. I believe that my chrome have successfully write data to disk. Here is the situation, I rarely shutdown my mac. I usually just lock my screen and leave my chrome open. However, I close my extension quite often. Each time, when I reopen my extension, it can read the data correctly.

Comment: The data for my extension is lost only when I reboot my macOS during it restarts. If my data is lost, why my bookmarks remains.